# Angular event binding issue

Tags: angular

How to pass a value using event binding in angular. For example, I want to execute `function('yes')` if `button 1` is clicked and `function('no')` if `button 2` is clicked. How to make the below code work without using the input fields?

code:

```html
<button (click)="function('yes')"></button>
<button (click)="function('yes')"></button>
```

Comment: Unclear what you mean. Are the functions called ‘yes’ and ‘no’..?

Comment: What's the result of this code? This should work if you properly write your method in your `component.ts`.

Comment: As you said, if both the buttons are different then bind the similar click event to other button (click) = "function('no')" .

Comment: What are function names ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a method that you want to call on click event in your typescript file of the component:

```js
export class YourComponent {

  ...

  onClick(event) {
    // Handle the event
  }
}
```

And you bind the method to your button:

```html
<button (click)="onClick('yes')"></button>
<button (click)="onClick('no')"></button>
```